# Fixing a javascript search with a table

Tags: javascript, html

I found an answer here for creating a javascript search to hide and show Div's with a certain class tag, and it worked fine. Then I introduced a table, and it did not work. So I did a test where I put the class to search for (target) in a p tag inside the td, and gave a surrounding div a second class. I added two lines to the javascript to also hide the div's class. That worked.

However, when I add more td's to my table, it does not hide the entire row wrapped in the div. It only hides the paragraph ... so all the rows are still shown, but the paragraph with my target tag gets blanked out.

The code I'm including has the table that works, and the table that does NOT work commented out. I've been beating my head against this for hours, and as NOT a javascript guy, I think I've gotten as far as I can.

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('rowhide');
    
  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      nodes[i].style.display = "block";
      divsToHide[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      nodes[i].style.display = "none";
      divsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
<body>
<table align="center" width="20%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
      <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please enter a search term.." title="Type in a name">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>


<table width=960 border=0 align=center>

<!--
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu2><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ABIT&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ABIT</a></td><td><p class=target>A BIT OF NATURE</p></td><td><p>221 E SPRING ST</p></td><td><p>ST MARYS</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>45885</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ACCEN&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ACCEN</a></td><td><p class=target>ACCENT FLORAL</p></td><td><p>1330 BECK AVE</p></td><td><p>CODY</p></td><td><p>WV</p></td><td><p>82414</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu2><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ADAMS&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ADAMS</a></td><td><p class=target>ADAMS COUNTY FLORIST  GIFTS</p></td><td><p>209 W MAIN ST</p></td><td><p>WEST UNION</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>45693</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ALVIS&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ALVIS</a></td><td><p class=target>ALVIS FLORAL</p></td><td><p>108 MAIN STREET</p></td><td><p>RAINELLE</p></td><td><p>WV</p></td><td><p>25962</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu2><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ENCHA&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ENCHA</a></td><td><p class=target>AN ENCHANTED GARDEN</p></td><td><p>620 WHEELING AVE</p></td><td><p>CAMBRIDGE</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>43725</p></td></tr></div>
-->

<div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">A BIT OF NATURE</p></td></tr></div>
<div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">ACCENT FLORAL</p></td></tr></div>
<div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">ADAMS COUNTY FLORIST  GIFTS</p></td></tr></div>
<div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">ALVIS FLORAL</p></td></tr></div>
<div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">AN ENCHANTED GARDEN</p></td></tr></div>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('rowhide');
    
  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      nodes[i].style.display = "block";
      divsToHide[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      nodes[i].style.display = "none";
      divsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<body>
<table align="center" width="20%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
      <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please enter a search term.." title="Type in a name">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>


<table width=960 border=0 align=center>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='tmenu2 rowhide'><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ABIT&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ABIT</a></td><td><p class=target>A BIT OF NATURE</p></td><td><p>221 E SPRING ST</p></td><td><p>ST MARYS</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>45885</p></td></tr>
        <tr class='tmenu rowhide'><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ACCEN&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ACCEN</a></td><td><p class=target>ACCENT FLORAL</p></td><td><p>1330 BECK AVE</p></td><td><p>CODY</p></td><td><p>WV</p></td><td><p>82414</p></td></tr>
        <tr class='tmenu2 rowhide'><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ADAMS&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ADAMS</a></td><td><p class=target>ADAMS COUNTY FLORIST  GIFTS</p></td><td><p>209 W MAIN ST</p></td><td><p>WEST UNION</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>45693</p></td></tr>
        <tr class='tmenu rowhide'><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ALVIS&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ALVIS</a></td><td><p class=target>ALVIS FLORAL</p></td><td><p>108 MAIN STREET</p></td><td><p>RAINELLE</p></td><td><p>WV</p></td><td><p>25962</p></td></tr>
        <tr class='tmenu2 rowhide'><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ENCHA&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ENCHA</a></td><td><p class=target>AN ENCHANTED GARDEN</p></td><td><p>620 WHEELING AVE</p></td><td><p>CAMBRIDGE</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>43725</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width=960 border=0 align=center>
    <div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">A BIT OF NATURE</p></td></tr></div>
    <div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">ACCENT FLORAL</p></td></tr></div>
    <div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">ADAMS COUNTY FLORIST  GIFTS</p></td></tr></div>
    <div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">ALVIS FLORAL</p></td></tr></div>
    <div class="rowhide"><tr class=tmenu><td><p class="target">AN ENCHANTED GARDEN</p></td></tr></div>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Remove the `<div></div>` outside all the `<tr></tr>` tags. It is breaking the table format. Add the class `rowhide` to each `tr` tag.

Css also has to be added if the table structure should not be broken while searching.

Comment: Thanks Gautham. So my misunderstanding was actually with adding the second class tag. I didn't realize I could do that or how, which made me try the div. Your solution was simple and didn't even add much to my code. I actually write the HTML with ASP as I loop through the data.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

All you needed to do was put the script below the rest of the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <body>
    <table align="center" width="20%">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 10px">
          <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please enter a search term.." title="Type in a name">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>


    <table width=960 border=0 align=center>

      <!--
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu2><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ABIT&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ABIT</a></td><td><p class=target>A BIT OF NATURE</p></td><td><p>221 E SPRING ST</p></td><td><p>ST MARYS</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>45885</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ACCEN&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ACCEN</a></td><td><p class=target>ACCENT FLORAL</p></td><td><p>1330 BECK AVE</p></td><td><p>CODY</p></td><td><p>WV</p></td><td><p>82414</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu2><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ADAMS&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ADAMS</a></td><td><p class=target>ADAMS COUNTY FLORIST  GIFTS</p></td><td><p>209 W MAIN ST</p></td><td><p>WEST UNION</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>45693</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ALVIS&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ALVIS</a></td><td><p class=target>ALVIS FLORAL</p></td><td><p>108 MAIN STREET</p></td><td><p>RAINELLE</p></td><td><p>WV</p></td><td><p>25962</p></td></tr></div>
<div class=rowhide><tr class=tmenu2><td><a href=CustomerTest.asp?CustNumber=00125ENCHA&Ship=Here class=listlink>00125ENCHA</a></td><td><p class=target>AN ENCHANTED GARDEN</p></td><td><p>620 WHEELING AVE</p></td><td><p>CAMBRIDGE</p></td><td><p>OH</p></td><td><p>43725</p></td></tr></div>
-->

      <div class="rowhide">
        <tr class=tmenu>
          <td>
            <p class="target">A BIT OF NATURE</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="rowhide">
        <tr class=tmenu>
          <td>
            <p class="target">ACCENT FLORAL</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="rowhide">
        <tr class=tmenu>
          <td>
            <p class="target">ADAMS COUNTY FLORIST GIFTS</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="rowhide">
        <tr class=tmenu>
          <td>
            <p class="target">ALVIS FLORAL</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="rowhide">
        <tr class=tmenu>
          <td>
            <p class="target">AN ENCHANTED GARDEN</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

    </table>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var input = document.getElementById("Search");
        var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
        var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
        var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('rowhide');

        for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
          if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
            nodes[i].style.display = "block";
            divsToHide[i].style.display = "block";
          } else {
            nodes[i].style.display = "none";
            divsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Exaplantion:**

`<script>` tags inside the body of a HTML5 document are only interpreting the code above it. That is why if you want it to use the whole document you put it in the head section of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do,

1. Remove the `<div></div>` outside all the `<tr></tr>` tags. This is breaking the table format. Change the tr classes to "`tmenu`"
2. Take the following element `var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('tmenu');`
   and modify the `divsToHide`

Check the final code,
https://codepen.io/pritamthecoder/pen/wvWLeoP